# How can we handle speakers play/pause button events in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

How to get events/ callback from Bluetooth play/ pause button in iOS?

I have multiple speakers with version 2.1 and 4.0

I have tried with Core Bluetooth framework but not getting device in

```
    centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
```

Comment: Look for `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:`?

Comment: @Larme Yes. I was able to get event from remoteControlReceivedWithEvent
But I need to take the voice from speaker's microphone instead of playing songs from the music player. Is it possible
Can you provide code for same?